# javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator is abruptly ending output when nearing the end of file

Tags: java, json

I'm coding an application to accept input from a Json file and sort it. I have a function that takes a sorted ArrayList of JsonObjects and writes them to a temp file (for use in an external merge sort later on). The problem I'm having is that when the JsonGenerator is writing the final JsonObject to file, it quits abruptly during the output, leaving the file unfinished and unusable.

I've tried enabling pretty printing, changing the sample file size, doublechecked that the data was correct in the ArrayList of JsonObjects. Nothing has worked.

Here is the function in question:

```
public void writeTempDataToFile(ArrayList<JsonObject> jsobs, File file){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            JsonGeneratorFactory jsonGeneratorFactory = Json.createGeneratorFactory(Collections.singletonMap(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true));
            JsonGenerator jWrite = jsonGeneratorFactory.createGenerator(fos);
            jWrite.writeStartObject();
            jWrite.writeStartArray("results");
            for(JsonObject jsob : jsobs){
                jWrite.writeStartObject();
                jsob.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    jWrite.write(key, value);
                });
                jWrite.writeEnd();
            }
            jWrite.writeEnd();
            jWrite.writeEnd();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);}

    }
```

This is the error message I received when reading in the incomplete JsonObject during the external merge sort performed later. The action being performed during the error is adding the incomplete JsonObject to an ArrayList of

```
JsonObjects. 
javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token=EOF at (line no=411011, column no=7671, offset=19889551). Expected tokens are: [STRING]
```

Here is a sample of the output. The first JsonObject is what it should look like, the second is the final object to be written, and it shows where the output abruptly stops.

```
{
            "classification": "Class II",
            "center_classification_date": "20121025",
            "report_date": "20121031",
            "postal_code": "08816-2108",
            "termination_date": "20141007",
            "recall_initiation_date": "20120904",
            "recall_number": "D-031-2013",
            "city": "East Brunswick",
            "event_id": "63384",
            "distribution_pattern": "Nationwide",
            "openfda": {
            },
            "recalling_firm": "Raritan Pharmaceuticals, Inc.",
            "voluntary_mandated": "Voluntary: Firm Initiated",
            "state": "NJ",
            "reason_for_recall": "Microbial Contamination of Non-Sterile Products: Product is being recalled due to possible microbial contamination by C. difficile discovered in the raw material.",
            "initial_firm_notification": "E-Mail",
            "status": "Terminated",
            "product_type": "Drugs",
            "country": "United States",
            "product_description": "Premier Value Fiber Plus Calcium Supplement Capsules, 120 capsules per bottle, Distributed by: Chain Drug Consortium, LLC, Boca Raton, FL, UPC 8-40986-01987-6",
            "code_info": "Lot 15087, Exp 08/15",
            "address_1": "8 Joanna Ct",
            "address_2": "",
            "product_quantity": "96 bottles"
        },
        {
            "classification": "Class II",
            "center_classification_date": "20121025",
            "report_date": "20121031",
            "postal_code": "08816-2108",
            "termination_date": "20141007",
            "recall_initiation_date": "20120904",
            "recall_number": "D-026-2013",
            "city": "East Brunswick",
            "event_id": "63384",
            "distribution_pattern": "Nationwide",
            "openfda": {
            },
            "recalling_firm": "Raritan Pharmaceuticals, Inc.",
            "voluntary_mandated": "Volun
```

I expect the output to be a complete Json file with all brackets closed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the JsonGenerator before closing the FileOutputStream (it is most likely using an internal character buffer which needs to be flushed).

Comment: @Aluxxen No worries.  you'll quickly learn that "truncated file" almost invariably means some stream was not appropriately closed/flushed.  (Also, make sure you mark the answer "correct" so the next reader knows that this answer solved the problem.)